# После установки Project Reunion 0.5 отсутствует тип проекта WinUI3 in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, winui3

Моя версия винды 19042.870, стоит самая последняя мартовская Visual Studio 2019 Preview. Хочу создать WinUI3 in UWP проект, но его почему-то нет! Desktop есть, а UWP нет.

[image: Окно создания проекта]

Читаю [требования](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/project-reunion/get-started-with-project-reunion#set-up-your-development-environment):

- Universal Windows Platform development
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)

Это все установлено. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Что за фильтр Project Reunion?

Comment: @aepot Project Reunion - это тоже, что и WinUI3, новое название от microsoft. Без фильтра тоже нет типа проекта :(

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/apps/winui/winui3/get-started-winui3-for-uwp _Чтобы использовать шаблоны проектов WinUI 3 для UWP, описанные в этой статье, настройте компьютер разработки и установите Project Reunion 0.5 Preview._

Comment: Project Reunion 0.5 Preview установлено, конечно. Выбираю фильтры  C# , Windows и WinUI - проекта WinUI in UWP нет!

Comment: и дело не в фильтрах если их вообще не выбирать, в полном списке тоже нет проекта

Comment: Причем, это уже второй компьютер с такой засадой. UWP и там, и там работает без проблем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в источнике установки Project Reunion 0.5 extension. Если его поставить самый новый по умолчанию из Visual Studio Marketplace, то там нет UWP.

Как решить проблему:

- удалить расширение Project Reunion 0.5
- отключить автоматическое обновление расширений в Visual Studio
- скачать и поставить расширение по [ссылке](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/9/8/9981a84b-8fd8-4645-9dce-c62761601f17/ProjectReunion.Extension.vsix)

Процесс описан, как оказалось, [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/apps/project-reunion/get-started-with-project-reunion#set-up-your-development-environment)

ЕЩЕ: оказывается в Project Reuinion 0.5 была отключена поддержка универсальных приложений UWP и она должна снова появиться только в релизе 0.8.

Comment: Ну правильно. Потому что половина того, что сейчас реализовано в uwp, отсутствует в project reuinion.

Comment: @Ivan, ну что-то отсутствует, но тем не менее в версии 0.5 prerelease поддержка UWP очень даже прекрасно была, потом ее отключили, теперь снова в 0.8 обещают включить :)